# phpMyAdmin SQL Dump - Pattern for repetition of "INSERT INTO" lines

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to mimic the SQL dump function from phpMyAdmin with a Java PrintWriter and everything is working so far but I don't see the pattern for the "INSERT INTO" repetition.

Example:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`value`) VALUES
(0),
(1),
... <-- 975 lines hidden
(977),
(978);
INSERT INTO `table` (`value`) VALUES
(979),
(981),
... <-- 948 lines hidden
(1929),
(1930);
INSERT INTO `table` (`value`) VALUES
(1931),
(1932),
... <-- 963 lines hidden
```

The number of lines between the "INSERT INTO" statements vary, but are the same for different tables.

Because my tables increase in size regulary I need to determine this numbers to implement in my code.

---

### Answer

So, thanks to Sloan Thrashers answer and the the source code of phpMyAdmin on gitHub I found out, that the maximum length of a sql query is by default set to 50000.

The solution in my personal case:

I use a variable to count the characters so far in the current query and when I hit 50000, I insert a new "INSERT INTO" query.

Now my line-per-line Java-generated .sql file is exactly the same as the exported file from phpMyAdmin's export function and will pass a compare-files check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do an export of a table in phpAdmin, one of the settings for the export is number of records per insert. So as you loop through the records when you generate the values, you end one insert and "re-start" it when the record count reaches that number.

Usually, you vary that setting based on record size. This isn't to accommodate mySQL as much as it is to allow someone to edit the export if the file size is too large to email or upload, etc. and split it into multiple files. Another reason you might want to split the files might be due to limitations on statement size in a particular mySQL installation (rare).

In your case, you might pick a number based on the record size. Exports like your example might use a high number (3000 + ?), Exports of tables with a lot of columns, or with large columns might use a smaller number (50?).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Is there a documentation how this number is determined if you use the default settings? So maybe use a new "INSERT INTO" if the number of characters from all values combines exceed a certain value?

Comment: Not that I've seen, but you might find something. Mostly it intuitive, and based on the table schema. Add up the column sizes to get a rough idea.

Comment: That sounds like a high bar to meet, especially because that choice phpAdmin makes can vary from run to run, or between versions.